# Unit of integral windup reset parameter?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, theory, terminology

What is the unit of integral windup reset parameter? Is it the same as the unit of time, **seconds**?

Comment: hi! This is probably a language problem on my side, because I didn't learn control theory in English. But: What, in a formula, is the *integral windup reset parameter*? I've heard of *integral windup*, but not of a *integral windup reset parameter*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an integral parameter \$k_i\$, with units of seconds.

There is a reset parameter \$\frac{1}{k_i}\$, with units of resets/minute.

There is no parameter *integral windup reset*.